# Return String instead of DateTime if LINQ Query NULL

Tags: linq, datatables, predicate

I am using JQuery Datatables with my MVC 5 application. I am implementing sorting on one of my datatables within my MVC Controller. One of the columns displays dates to the user, and I want them to be able to sort this column, which works fine.

```
//Get index of column to be sorted
var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);

Func<survey_status, DateTime> orderingFunctionDate;

orderingFunctionDate = (c => c.InitiatedDate == null ? default(DateTime) : c.InitiatedDate.Value);
```

The problem is, at the moment, if `c.InitiatedDate` is NULL, then I return the default date `01/01/000`1, otherwise I return the actual date recorded in the Database.

I don't like that I am returning `01/01/0001` to the user, it isn't great usability and could confuse them. Instead, I'd like to return something like "No date available" if `c.InitiatedDate` is NULL.

The problem is I can't replace

```
orderingFunctionDate = (c => c.InitiatedDate == null ? default(DateTime) : c.InitiatedDate.Value);
```

with

```
orderingFunctionDate = (c => c.InitiatedDate == null ? "No date available" : c.InitiatedDate.Value);
```

because the Function `Func<survey_status, DateTime> orderingFunctionDate` is returning a DateTime, not string and in making this change I get an error `no implicit conversion between string and DateTime`.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a nullabel DateTime and return `null` instead of a default date. Change your function prototype to:

```
Func<survey_status, DateTime?> orderingFunctionDate;
```

And the content to:

```
orderingFunctionDate = (c => c.InitiatedDate);
```

Then I believe in jQuery DataTables you can specify a value to use when data is null.